# How can I create a form that allow user to upload new image or select from uploaded to set as profile image?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, upload, carrierwave

I'm using carierwave to allow users of my rails app to upload images to their gallary. How can I create a form that allow user to upload new image or select from uploaded to set as profile image?

Answer (score 0):

just add the appropriate attribute to your form and you're good to go.

For exemple:

```
 <%= form_for @user, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
    <p>
      <label>My Avatar URL:</label>
      <%= image_tag(@user.avatar_url) if @user.avatar? %>
      <%= f.text_field :remote_avatar_url %>
    </p>
 <% end %>
```